# How to implement a form to update the quantity?

Tags: django, django-orm

How to implement a form to update the quantity Car? I have no idea how to do it. Thanks

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField()    

class GarageCar(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car')
    garage = models.ForeignKey('Garage')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Garage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Garage_Name", max_length=30)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField('Car', through='GarageCar', blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_garage', verbose_name='Owner Garage')
```

In this way updates the quantity:

```
In [2]: c = Car.objects.get(id=1) #here I need car ID

In [3]: g = Garage.objects.get(owner=1)

In [4]: q = 33 #here I need data from form

In [5]: c= GarageCar.objects.filter(car=c, garage=g).update(quantity=q)
```

views:

```
def show(request):
    user = request.user
    garage = Garage.objects.get(owner=user)

    return render_to_response('garage.html', {'garage': garage, 'form':form})
```

in garage.html:

```
{% for item in garage.garagecar_set.all %}
        Car:      {{item.car.name}}
        Price:    {{item.car.price}} 
        Quantity: {{item.quantity}} 
        ID:       {{item.car.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

in forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class QuantityForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.IntegerField
```

How to create ORM query to update quantity?

How to display a form field next to each car in template (with button "Update")?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for forms? Please say what specifically you found confusing.

Comment: Yes. I read a description of the form in Django Docs. My problems are: 1. How to create ORM query to update quantity?

2. How to display a form field next to each car in template (with button "Update")? Please, any hint

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll be interested in FormSets, specifically InlineFormSets:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view

If you want to make it stupidly easy (possibly at the expense of understanding how it all works), you can use my generic views for exactly this use case.

My library: https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views

Then...

views.py:

```
import extra_views 

class EditProductReviewsView(extra_views.InlineFormSetView):
    model = Garage
    inline_model = GarageCar
    fields = ('quantity', )
    template_name = 'garage.html'
```

garage.html:

```
<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ formset.management_form }}

<table>
{% for form in formset %}
<tr>
<td>{{ form.instance.car.name }}</td>
<td>{{ form.instance.car.price }}</td>
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<td>
{{ field }}
</td>
{% endfor %}
<div style="display: none;">
{% for field in form.hidden_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
</div>
<td>{{ form.quantity }}</td>
<td>{{ form.instance.car.id }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>


<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I've not tested this example, I can't remember if you'll need to add the id field to the `fields` tuple or not. But the basic gist should be right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to do it from scratch. How to do it simply by using the InlineFormSets?

Comment: In the example in the link (the Django docs one), simply change Author to be Garage and Book to be GarageCar, and instance to be the specific Garage you're concerned with. The template logic should be identical to what I've posted.

You can also pass as fields parameter to inlineformset_factory, which allows you to restrict the fields in the same way as my example.